# Joda Time subtracting 24 hours from an instance of MutableDateTime, I would like to know why

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

I do not understand why `MutableDateTime.setDate()` is setting the time to "yesterday" (see the log timestamp hours - it is 20:28).  Is this timezone related?  Do I need to set something on the formatter?

I would expect that after calling setDate with "10/27/2010", the date would be the same as the parsed date 00:00 EDT 10/27/10, instead of 20:28 EDT 10/26/10.  This is 24 hours ago from "now".

What am I missing here, or how should I edit the code to get the desired result?  I am new to Joda Time, and would like to solve this mystery.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatterJ = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter timestampFormatJ = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm zzz MM/dd/yy");

MutableDateTime startDate = new MutableDateTime();

log.info("parsed date " + 
    timestampFormatJ.print(dateFormatterJ.parseMutableDateTime(startDateString)));

startDate.setDate((dateFormatterJ.parseMutableDateTime(startDateString)));

log.info("startDate: " + timestampFormatJ.print(startDate));
```

In this case, `startDateString` is simply "10/27/2010".

here is the log output:

```
10-27 20:28:55 INFO parsed date: 00:00 EDT 10/27/10
10-27 20:28:55 INFO startDate: 20:28 EDT 10/26/10
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing a string that does not contain a GMT offset or time-zone ID, you must do one of three things:

- do nothing, and accept that the string is parsed in the default time zone
- specify the time zone to parse in using `withZone()` on the formatter
- use `parseLocalDate()` instead of `parseMutableDateTime()`

The last is the preferred solution, as it correctly parses the data that was actually input, which was a date without time, offset or zone.

Using `parseLocalDate()` in the test code correctly parses the date.

Comment: a google for +"parseLocalDate" +joda returns a single google groups post from June and some code in GWT.  I did try it using withZone() before looking at the source and the result is the same.  It seems like even though I specify a zone, the code in MutableDateTime sees it on my Chronology, then goes and shifts it into UTC instead of shifting it into the timezone of the MutableDateTime.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer would be, because the javadoc says so.

> public void setDate(ReadableInstant
> instant)
>
> Set the date from another
> instant. **The time part of this object
> will be unaffected.**
>
> Parameters:
> instant - an instant to copy the date
> from, time part ignored
>
> Throws:
> IllegalArgumentException - if the
> object is invalidobject is invalid

When Joda says 'Date' it means the human meaning of the word Date. "The year-month-day portion of this value",  not the logical equivalent of a java.util.Date.  (the whole point of joda being to introduce some natural, sensible, semantics to handling date and time.)

EDIT:
To answer your 'how to fix' question, simply do:

```
MutableDateTime startDate = new MutableDateTime(dateFormatterJ.parseMutableDateTime(startDateString));
```

Or else manually zero out the time portions of course.

EDIT 2: Hmm, I apparently did not read carefully enough, this is only half of the answer.  Will check.

EDIT 3: well this bugged me so much that I took a minute to look for it.

```
public void setDate(final ReadableInstant instant) {
    long instantMillis = DateTimeUtils.getInstantMillis(instant);
    Chronology instantChrono = DateTimeUtils.getInstantChronology(instant);
    DateTimeZone zone = instantChrono.getZone();
    if (zone != null) {
        instantMillis = zone.getMillisKeepLocal(**DateTimeZone.UTC**, instantMillis);
    }
    setDate(instantMillis);
}
```

For some reason, it's rolling your absolute time forward into UTC before setting the date.  So you give it 10/27/2010 00:00 EDT and it sets the absolute magnitude of time to the number of milliseconds that represent 10/27/2010 00:00 UTC, which of course is only 6 or 7 PM the day before.  Then it finds the EDT date value of that to be 10/26.

Couldn't say if that's somehow intended or if it's a bug that's been there for 2 years or what.)

Comment: Thank you, Affe.  Your fix of newing up the MutableDateTime with the parsed date string instead of using setDate() worked.  The explanation into the root cause is also much appreciated.  I would interpret this as a bug, but there may be differing opinions.

Comment: I've created a ticket for this issue - https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3097754&group_id=97367&atid=617889